# does Java have API wrappers around subversion and Git?

Tags: java, svn, git

Curious if there any API wrappers for Git and Subversion for Java?

I want to be able to pullup the changesets and souce code (and diffs) from Subversion and Git repos.

Is this possible? Any pre-built APIs?

Comment: which keywords did you ask Google for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick google search found some results, although I can't say I've used them so their usefulness is unknown

- [JavaGit](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/): "JavaGit is a Java API that provides access to git repositories. Our goal is to provide a library with an easy-to-use API that is intuitive for developers new to git and developers who are veteran git users." According to their FAQ it just uses the command line git command behind the scenes
- [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/): An implementation of git in Java
- [svnkit](http://svnkit.com/): Implementation of SVN in Java.

Comment: It is kinda suspicious that JavaGit developers themselves use svn to host the project.

Comment: I can vouch for svnkit.  I've used it to connect to our svn repo as part of our deploy process.  The only thing I would comment on is that it is a little weird to use.  But once you figure out what it is expecting it works well.

Answer (score 3):

[jGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) is an implementation of git in Java.

[SvnClientAdapter](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html) will connect to SVN using various different methods.

Comment: I need to hook into GIT, not re-implement GIT in java? or is that a API wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

JGit is an implementation of Git, so if you are looking for just an API which routes to the native git implementation, it will not do the trick.

JavaGit just does not work. I tried it under win64 with msysgit 1.8.1 and,... well it just does not work. Probably it was tested under another OS and older version of git.One can go ahead and fix JavaGit for their purposes - the code is far from complex. The maturity of the source is not impressive though - there are unimplemented stubs, exception swallowing etc. I'd say it's an unfinished project by otherwise well-intended people.

Maybe another alternative is to take the git command class from http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3033 and decouple it from intellij infrastructure. That is something I would pursue.

It's always an option, if your usecases are simple, to implement your own API, perhaps reusing a commandline abstraction library such as http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [svnkit](http://svnkit.com/) for a java-based subversion implemention. There are also subversion bindings to java distributed with subversion at http://subversion.tigris.org/

[jgit](http://www.jgit.org/) has a java implementation for git.